# Setting Cookies errors

Tags: php, cookies

I am Trying to set cookies but can't, My Code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($data)>0) {
            if (isset($_POST["loggedin"])) {
                setcookie("RAUSERNAME", $USERNAME,time() + (86400 * 365 * 1000),"/");
                setcookie("RAPASSWORD", $PASSWORD,time() + (86400 * 365 * 1000),"/");
            }
            $_SESSION["SRAUSERNAME"] = $USERNAME;
            $_SESSION["SRAPASSWORD"] = $PASSWORD;
            header("location: ../");
        }
```

By echo-ing cookie, it doesn't prints something or is not setted at all.

Comment: Hard to answer the question when we don't know what is not working, however You should not set the password as a cookie, and depending on a user controlled variable (`loggedin`) might be unsecured as well.

Comment: This is only for test purposes.

Comment: Try `print_r($_COOKIE);` If nothing print there is some other problem with your conditions which is logged in or something else.

Comment: Test purposes or not 'it doesn't work' is not something anyone can help you with. You should describe the behaviour you expect, the behaviour you're encountering, how they differ, any other information (errors in logs? checks on the clientside?). Take a look at [ask]

Comment: try to use die() inside your post condition check try printing $_POST["loggedin"] check wheather it actually gets there

Comment: @ChMuhammadSohaib is your condition working ?

Comment: die does'nt gives any error

Comment: @OwaisAslam what do you mean?

Comment: @ChMuhammadSohaib are you getting in to `if (isset($_POST["loggedin"]))`

Comment: Yes, I am getting in

Comment: @ChMuhammadSohaib are you getting values in `$USERNAME`, `$PASSWORD` ? your cookie function is working at my side.

Comment: Yes, I am and found the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, You all for suggestions. The real problem was in the timings of the cookie which i setted, after reducing it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This..

```
<?php 

if (mysqli_num_rows($data)>0) {



            if (isset($_POST["loggedin"])) {

              $cookie_name = $_POST["USERNAME"];
              $cookie_passoword = $_POST["PASSWORD"];

                setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_passoword,time() + (86400 * 30),"/");  // 1 Day   oR  ( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),"/"); // For 1 Year

            }

              $_SESSION[$cookie_name] = $USERNAME;
              $_SESSION[$cookie_passoword] = $PASSWORD;

            if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_passoword]) ) {

                echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "'  and '".$cookie_passoword."' is not set!";
            } else {

                echo "Cookie Name Is '" . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]. "' is set!<br>";
                echo "Password  is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_passoword];
            }


            header("location: ../");
        }
?>
```